# PHP: by-reference-function with boolean as return value – strange notice

Tags: php, function

I have a function which returns a referenced value by default – however, the function should return `false` if something went wrong during processing things in the function.

The function is declared as follows.

```
function &find($idx, $pref_array = false) {

    if ($pref_array === false)
        $pref_array = &$this->preferences;

    foreach ($pref_array as $key => $data) {
        if ($key == $idx) {
            return $pref_array[$idx];
        }
        else if (is_array($data)) {
            $res = &$this->find($idx, &$pref_array[$key]);
            if ($res !== false)
                return $res;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

PHP gives me a notice that "Only variable references should be returned by reference". Do I really need to put `$result = false;` in my code and return `$result`? That would be somehow ridiculous.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what php version u use ?

Comment: I'm on the latest, PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that that is not a good way to code a general find function because it would be impossible to determine if a `FALSE` value returned from the function means that the value of the searched item was in fact `FALSE` or if the searched item was not found.

If you know that `FALSE` are not legal values than its OK, otherwise you should implement the find function in a different way.
For example this way:

```
function find($idx, & $found_value, $pref_array = false) {
   // pseudocode
   if found:
     $found_value = $array[$idx]
     return true
   else:
     return false
}
```

This way you can always know if the requested item was found by checking the value returned from the function and if the returned value is TRUE you would have a reference to the found item in the variable referenced by the `$found_value` argument.

Finally, this way you don't get any strange notice ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer – looks like a clever alternative.